# What's the property of a metric that defines if an increasing value is good or bad called?

Tags: terminology, loss-functions

For instance, an increasing trend for a revenue metric is good, while bad for something like the number of defects per million. What is the correct technical term to describe this property of a metric.

Comment: A *loss* function?

Comment: @NeilG What would the possible values be if we call this property the loss function?

Comment: The value of a loss function is a real number.  Loss functions need to have global minima.  Because they are used only by comparing losses, there is no generality lost in supposing the minimum is zero.